# probability that the coin is the 2-headed coin?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

A bag contains 1000 coins. 
    999 are normal, fair coins; 1 coin has 2 heads.

You pick a coin at random from the bag. 
    You flip it 10 times. 
    You get 10 heads.

What is the probability that the coin is the 2-headed coin?

Comment: Please do not use codeblock for anything that is not actually code. Quoteblock using > or emphasis or strong emphasis using * should be applied where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: you picked a fair coin and it came up heads 10 times in a row.

$P = 0.999\cdot \frac {1}{2^{10}}$

Or you picked the fake coin

$P = 0.001$

$\frac {0.001}{0.999\cdot \frac {1}{2^{10}} + 0.001} = \frac {1.024}{0.999 + 1.024} = \frac {1.024}{2.023}$

Comment: Did you use bayes theorem? It looks like an intuitive use of the definition of probability,  i.e.  P(event)  = #favorable event / # total event, but using probabilities.

Comment: Does it make a difference?  I answered this 3 years ago, not exactly sure what I was thinking.  But, Bayes theorem ~  $P(A|B) = P(B|A)\frac {P(A)}{P(B)}.$  If $P(A)$ is pulling the 2 headed coin, and $P(B)$ is flipping 10 heads, then $P(B|A) = 1.$  What is shown is $\frac {P(A)}{P(B)}$

Answer (score 1):

You are right about using Bayes' Theorem. Let's systematically assemble the ingredients
you need to apply that theorem.

Let $T$ be the event that you pick a two-headed coin; $P(T) = 1/1000.$
Let $F$ be the event that you pick a fair coin; $P(F) = 999/1000.$
Let $E$ be the event of getting ten heads in a row;
$P(E|T) = 1$ and $P(E|F) = (1/2)^{10}.$

Bayes' Theorem:
$$P(T|E) = \frac{P(T\cap E)}{P(E)}
= \frac{P(T\cap E)}{P(T\cap E)+P(F\cap E)}.$$

Now, $P(T \cap E) = P(T)P(E|T) = ?$ 
And $P(F \cap E) = P(F)P(E|F) = ?$

I'll let you put the pieces together.